# Uploading files to openshift without using git?

Tags: node.js, github, openshift

I'm currently using github.com to push and deploy my files. One of these files contains a username and password for an API on a website. Is there a way to upload files to openshift without publicly exposing saved authentication credentials on github? To be more specific, I have a config.js file that has a username and a password and I don't want that to be stored on github, but used on openshift. Do I need to make a database instead?

Is there a better way to deploy node.js apps? I don't have money to spend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use winscp to log into my app. Using winscp I then copy my config.ini file which contains my secret stuff than I don't want on github to the Openshift data directory. From there my app just loads that file and retrieves the necessary information.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! When I'm using node.js how can I debug my application? For local host I'm able to use console.log to output things to my computer, but how would I see console.log on openshift?

Comment: Please accept my answer as correct if it was looking for. As for your 2nd question, you can use winscp or such to view your log files. Or "rhc tail <app name>" to stream current logging on openshift.